# Pandas: Clean up String column containing Single Quotes and Brackets using Regex?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I want to clean the following Pandas dataframe column, but in a single and efficient statement than the way I am trying to achieve it in the code below.

**Input:**

```
                  string
0  ['string', '#string']
1            ['#string']
2                     []
```

**Output:**

```
            string
0  string, #string
1          #string
2              NaN
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {"string": ["['string', '#string']", "['#string']", "[]"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['string'] = df['string'].astype(str).str.strip('[]')
df['string'] = df['string'].replace("\'", "", regex=True)
df['string'] = df['string'].replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

print(df)
```

Comment: What about `df['string'].astype(str).str.replace("^\[+|\]+$|'", "")`?

Comment: This works for the first two rows. Anyway to get `np.NaN` in there as well for the last row?

Comment: Then you need a conditional replacement.

Comment: ```df['string'] = df['string'].astype(str).str.replace("^\[+|\]+$|'", "").replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)``` Try this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
df['string'] = df['string'].astype(str).str.replace(r"^[][\s]*$|(^\[+|\]+$|')", lambda m: '' if m.group(1) else np.nan)
```

*Details*:

- `^[][\s]*$` - matches a string that only consists of zero or more `[`, `]` or whitespace chars
- `|` - or
- `(^\[+|\]+$|')` - captures into Group 1 one or more `[` chars at the start of string, or one or more `]` chars at the end of string or any `'` char.

If Group 1 matches, the replacement is an empty string (the match is removed), else, the replacement is `np.nan`.